# Javascript Select Boxes - Make Image appear rather than text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have 2 select boxes, with the first dropdown selection then populating the second select box. Once you have selected both your options a GO button appears to take you to a link based on your selection. I want to be able to change this GO button from text to an image.  The styling for it is below:

```
     if (!goButton) {
    //If the element doesn't exist, make it.
    goButton = document.createElement('button1');
    goButton.innerHTML = "Go!";
    goButton.style.display = "inline-block";
    goButton.style.fontWeight = "500";
    goButton.style.fontcolor = "white";
    item.parentNode.appendChild(goButton); //add it to the parent of the item argument.
    goButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'goButtonGo()');
    goButton.setAttribute('id', 'go-button');
  } else {
    //If it does exist, make sure you can see it.
    goButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With your button, you could just set a `background-image`.

```js
var button = document.createElement('button1');
button.style.display = "inline-block";
button.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://codepo8.github.io/canvas-images-and-pixels/img/horse.png)';
button.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
button.style.width = '100px';
button.style.height = '100px';
document.getElementById('box').appendChild(button);
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

You can also create an `<input type="image">` element

```js
var button = document.createElement('input');
button.type = 'image';
button.src = 'https://codepo8.github.io/canvas-images-and-pixels/img/horse.png';
document.getElementById('box').appendChild(button);
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping styling in a CSS instead of being handled by JS

```
.goButton {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
    background-image: url("the/url/of/your/image.jpg");
}
.goButton .selected {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then all you need to manage the styling is setting this code

```
if (goButton.className) goButton.className =  "selected";
else                    goButton.className += " selected";
```